# Зачем нужна функция init?

Tags: golang

Собственно вопрос полностью описан в заголовке)
В чем состоит необходимость в такой функции?

Comment: Для инициализации, что очевидно из её названия.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`init()` вызывается один раз при инициализации пакета, но толь ко после того как будут вызваны другие функции `init()` импортируемые в данном пакете.

Например пакет `A` импортирует пакет `B`, сначала `init()` запустится в пакете `B`, а потом в пакете `A`